# Hibernate Spring Named query to query in a list of objects

Tags: spring, hibernate, named-query

I have an Entity called ArtWork and the Entity has attribute `List<Style>` styles, the list may have n number of styles.

Style has attribute called title

I require a Hibernate query that returns all artworks which has a style title="Abstract"

-Thanks for your help

Comment: `select a from ArtWork a inner join a.styles style where style.title = 'Abstract'`

Comment: Thanks - TJ, Also help me if i have a list of styles say- 'Abstract', 'Geometric', 'Nature' as a parameter, can i write a query for it or should i iterate over them?

Comment: You don't need to iterate over the names, but provide a list of parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single title:

```
select a from ArtWork a inner join a.styles style where style.title = 'Abstract'
```

Multiple titles:

Provide a named parameter list.

```
List<String> titles = ... // Your titles
session.createQuery("from ArtWork a inner join a.styles style where style.title in (:titles)").setParameterList("titles", titles);
```

Comment: That was a cake walk..! Thanks TJ

Comment: TJ- additional help- is it possible return all records if the style list is empty?

Comment: I can't think of anything on top of my head for this. You could probably use two different queries based on whether the list is empty or not.

Comment: Thanks for your time TJ, will let you know in case of an efficient one

Comment: - TJ : I am looking into this JPA Specification executor, could not rightly implement it in our case. Facing a type mismatch for collections type in Style. Do you any idea on this? visit: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html - 2.5 specifications

Comment: What is the exception? What does the code look like? I would suggest you to create a new question with the details of the issues that you are facing.